# Firebird sort order with other character set

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

The sorting in this query does not take in account signs, only letters:

```
SELECT CAST(Text AS VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1) COLLATE NO_NO Result FROM (
select CAST('_Anon' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI as Text from RDB$DATABASE
UNION
SELECT CAST('Abba' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI AS Text from  RDB$DATABASE
UNION
SELECT CAST('Beatles' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI AS Text from  RDB$DATABASE)
ORDER BY Result
```

Expected sort order(non-alpha-numeric before any letter):

```
_Anon
Abba
Beatles
```

But I get:

```
Abba
_Anon
Beatles
```

The collation does not matter. If you delete "COLLATE NO_NO" it still sorts wrong.

Edit: Found that collation ES_ES sorts this correct, but it fails to sort Norwegian characters.

Is this a bug or am I missing something in this query?

What I'm trying to do is to get correct sort order in Norwegian, and none of the collations in UNICODE_CI_AI gives me the correct order.

Update: Expanded the example with another sub-query so that it clearer shows the point.

Comment: What order are you expecting, and what result do you get? Also I'd say that a sample of only `_Anon` and `Abba` are not really a very good indication of whether a sort is done well or not. BTW: have you tried specifying the collation in the [`order by`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-orderby)

Comment: Specifying the collation in the order by like:
ORDER BY Result COLLATION NO_NO does not help:(

Comment: Then it is very likely that is how the collation order is defined.

Comment: You could try to create a specific collation derived from the unicode collation, but it might not work correctly with the default ICU version included (because it doesn't contain the full ICU dataset).

Comment: If you can find an authoritative reference that the current sort order would be wrong for NO_NO, then you should file a bug at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE

Comment: I've just done a quick check, but it looks like most of the Firebird (non-unicode) collations handle non-alpha-numeric characters and control characters in 'ascii' order before any numbers (including fractions etc if in the character set) and letters.

Comment: I second Mark here. With only two samples shown the answer would be just "modify your query to end with `ORDER BY Result DESC` " - you really have to add more letters from ABC

Comment: The point of the example is that i would expect non-alpha-numeric characters to be sorted before any letters. So I expect it's a bug. More so after I found that COLLATION ES_ES sorts non-alpha-numeric the right way.
@MarkRotteveel How do you create a collation derived from the unicode collation?

Comment: Yes, it does like a bug; I also looked at the collation definition and I would have expected them to sort first, so I am not really sure what is going on. Consider filing a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE. Anyway, see the documentation for [`create collation`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-collation.html), but to be honest the documentation isn't very clear.

Comment: "non-alpha-numeric before any letter" - I think that is wrong. What I see is that alphanumeric is REMOVED from ordering. I mean, you get the following result: "Abba, Anon, Beatles" - see, it is correctly ordered.... It just OMITS the underscore like it never been there.

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not what happens: the `_` (and other non-alphanumerics) are sorted **after** alphanumerics. But the collation definition suggests they should be sorted first.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel would it be so, then "_Anon" should had been sorted AFTER "Beatles" not before them.

Comment: @Arioch'The You're right, I'm fully confused this whole thing. Still think it is a bug though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it probably is. But now it is in "bug compatibility" mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marks hint to look at the collation pointed me in the direction of a solution.

I do consider this a bug, so I was going to file a a bug report to firebirdsql, but found out [it's a "Won't fix" and the workaround below is the official fix](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4026).

Of all base collations defined ES_* is the only one with the attribute: SPECIALS-FIRST=1 set. In fact it's the only collation with any attribute set.

And that [attribute defines](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-collation.html#fblangref25-ddl-collation-specatt) that special characters should be sorted before alphanumeric characters.

So the workaround is to create a new collation based on the NO_NO collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION NO_NO_NOPAD_CI_SF
FOR ISO8859_1
FROM NO_NO
NO PAD
CASE INSENSITIVE
'SPECIALS-FIRST=1';
```

then using the new collation like this:

```
SELECT CAST(Text AS VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1) COLLATE NO_NO_NOPAD_CI_NUM_SF Result FROM (
select CAST('_Anon' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI as Text from RDB$DATABASE
UNION
SELECT CAST('Abba' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI AS Text from  RDB$DATABASE
UNION
SELECT CAST('Beatels' AS VARCHAR(20)) COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI AS Text from  RDB$DATABASE)
ORDER BY Result
```

Yields the expected result:

```
_Anon
Abba
Beatles
```

Comment: I indeed can understand the logic "do not change collations that are there for decades already". But indeed why not introducing new clean set of standard collations?..